# Nuclear Mass and stability

Tags: nuclear-physics

I was plotting the Ag$-109$ Mass parabola putting the Atomic number on the $x-$axis and the Mass of the nuclei on the $y-$axis (calculated as $M=Zm_p+(A-Z) m_n-B$).

I noticed that even if the Ag$-109$ ($Z=47$) is the stable element the minimum of the parabola is on $Z=48$. Is that possible?

Comment: Did you use Cd-110 or Cd-109 as required?

Comment: Cd_109, I took B values in order to calculate M from here http://amdc.impcas.ac.cn/masstables/Ame2016/mass16.txt

Comment: Why did you use $Zm_p+(N-Z)m_n-B$? Shouldn't it be $Zm_p+Nm_n-B$? Is this perhaps the reason for the discrepancy?

Comment: @Ben Crowell no I only made a mistake in writing the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, It is possible because the Q value of the electron capture process from 48 $\rightarrow$ 47 is (M initial - M final + electron mass) and not (M initial - M final)

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you look at the "Chart of the Nuclides". Here is a link [of an interactive version](http://www.nndc.bnl.gov/chart/reColor.jsp?newColor=beda) in the region of A=107. You can veiw the color scale for BE/A and see if the numbers agree with yours. The chart is the official version from the National Nuclear Data Center (NNDC) at Brookhaven National Lab. The full chart is shown here [for half-lives.](http://www.nndc.bnl.gov/chart/reColor.jsp?newColor=t12)

Comment: I know Ag-109 is the stable element (it has a B/A major than Cd-109.  The point is that calculating the Mass using the formula that I wrote above I obtain the Mass of Ag major than the mass of Cd. Is that possible?

Comment: Note that the NNDC is actually hosted at Brookhaven (bnl.gov which you linked to), not Los Alamos (lanl.gov).

Comment: @Jon Custer Yep. Thanks. I'll correct my answer now.

Answer (score -2):

The definitive place to look for nuclear stability would be the journal Nuclear Data Sheets. The article for A=109, [Jean Blachot, Nuclear Data Sheets 107 355-506 (2006)](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0090375206000032) is quite clear that the lowest energy nucleus is indeed $^{109}$Ag, which is 214.2keV more stable then $^{109}$Cd.

Comment: I know Ag-109 is the stable element (it has a B/A major than Cd-109.  The point is that calculating the Mass using the formula that I wrote above I obtain the Mass of Ag major than the mass of Cd. Is that possible?

Comment: @Tarlo_x - well, the difficulty is on your end, which I won't debug. The definitive table is available on line at http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1674-1137/41/3/030003/meta and you can check if your equation matches theirs.

Comment: My question is if it make sense that a nucleus less stable with same A of another one more stable has minor Mass (in theory, I don't need help in searching data)